# What code do I use to get the amount of boxes checked in the CheckBoxes?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am currently working on a lab assignment. I basically have to create a GUI with Javafx that prompts the user to make a pizza. Though instead of making it super complicated like picking out maybe the type of cheese or sauce I am allowed to use check boxes for the toppings. The issue that I have run into is figuring out which boxes have been checked so that I can calculate the final total into the equation at the end for the final price of the pizza. This is the code that I have right now using NetBeans. I can figure out the rest once I have the checked boxes amount so you don't really have to worry about the process return at the bottom thanks!

```
public PizzaPane()
{
    Font font = new Font(18);



    CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox("Bacon");
    CheckBox cb2 = new CheckBox("Peppers");
    CheckBox cb3 = new CheckBox("Sausage");
    CheckBox cb4 = new CheckBox("Extra Cheese");
    CheckBox cb5 = new CheckBox("Ham");
    CheckBox cb6 = new CheckBox("Onions");

    Button push = new Button("Total!");
    push.setOnAction(this::processReturn);

    Label outputLabel = new Label("Property Output:");
    outputLabel.setFont(font);
    GridPane.setHalignment(outputLabel, HPos.RIGHT);

    result = new Label("---");
    result.setFont(font);
    GridPane.setHalignment(result, HPos.CENTER);


    setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    setHgap(50);
    setVgap(20);
    setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
    setGridLinesVisible(false);



    add(cb1 , 1, 2);
    add(cb2 , 1, 3);
    add(cb3 , 1, 4);
    add(cb4 , 1, 5);
    add(cb5 , 1, 6);
    add(cb6 , 1, 7);
    add(push, 2, 0);
    add(outputLabel, 0, 1);
    add(result, 1, 1);






}
  public void processReturn(ActionEvent event)

{

    double fValue =(10);

    result.setText(fValue + "");
}
```

`enter code here`}

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [isSelected](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected()) method in the JCheckBox class to know the state of the checkbox. In your case you want to count the number of check boxes checked, so you have to have a counter to count the number of checkboxes as illustrated in the code below.

```
int numberOfCheckedBoxes = 0;

numberOfCheckedBoxes += (cb1 != null && cb1.isSelected() ? 1 : 0);
numberOfCheckedBoxes += (cb2 != null && cb1.isSelected() ? 1 : 0);
numberOfCheckedBoxes += (cb3 != null && cb1.isSelected() ? 1 : 0);
numberOfCheckedBoxes += (cb4 != null && cb1.isSelected() ? 1 : 0);
numberOfCheckedBoxes += (cb5 != null && cb1.isSelected() ? 1 : 0);
numberOfCheckedBoxes += (cb6 != null && cb1.isSelected() ? 1 : 0);

System.out.println("Number of Checked Boxes = " + numberOfCheckedBoxes);
```

A better design would be to declare all your ui components as instance variable, and instead have the above code in a method.

Comment: What exactly would it look like when changing everything out?

Comment: I already explained that in my answer. You should try that out by yourself.